# The order of template specializations in C++

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

Can the order in which template specializations appear in the code alter the meaning of the program? If so, then why?

Example:

Somewhere inside a source code

```
// specialization A
...
// specialization B
...
```

vs.

```
// specialization B
...
// specialization A
...
```

Will this always produce the same result?

Comment: No it wont. Think of: static variables whose init has side-effects, dependant definitions, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So long as a snippet of code that relies on the specialisations has already seen them, the order does not matter.

In other words, the order would matter with

```
// specialization A
// Some code where B would be a better match
// specialization B
```

Comment: But note this doesn't necessarily mean something must come between the two specializations. In particular, if "specialization A" is an explicit specialization definition and that definition *contains* "some code where B would be a better match" (and B has not been declared yet), bang, undefined behavior.  (This can normally be solved by declaring and then defining the specializations.)

Answer (score 36):

> The placement of explicit specialization declarations for function
>   templates, class templates, member functions of class templates,
>   static data members of class templates, member classes of class
>   templates, member class templates of class templates, member function
>   templates of class templates, member functions of member templates of
>   class templates, member functions of member templates of non-template
>   classes, member function templates of member classes of class
>   templates, etc., and the placement of partial specialization
>   declarations of class templates, member class templates of
>   non-template classes, member class templates of class templates, etc.,
>   can affect whether a program is well-formed according to the relative
>   positioning of the explicit specialization declarations and their
>   points of instantiation in the translation unit as specified above and
>   below. When writing a specialization, be careful about its location;
>   or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its
>   self-immolation.

Simply quoting section [14.7.3/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#7) of the *2011 International Standard for Programming Language C++*

**Yes... this is not a Joke**

Comment: This is [`[temp.expl.spec]/7`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#7) (I had to look for it, sorry I didn't blindly trust you on that one).

Comment: I had also to google it... I just remember that there was something in the standard as i found the description quite funny!

Comment: It's 17.8.3/7 in the C++17 draft. It even has more stuff in it. Turns out language lawyers _do_ have a sense of humour.

Comment: Here's a trimmed version of that quote (which I find easier to read): *"The placement of explicit specialization declarations [...] and the placement of partial specialization declarations [...] can affect whether a program is well-formed [...]. When writing a specialization, be careful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its self-immolation."*

Comment: I love how this passage contains a list of sixteen different varations on the template concept, followed by "etc."